# Laravel 5.4 Pusher Broadcasting

Tags: javascript, php

I am having the following error:

```
 Pusher : Couldn't get auth info from your webapp : 404
warn @ pusher.min.js:8
r.onreadystatechange @ pusher.min.js:8
pusher.min.js:8 Pusher : Couldn't get auth info from your webapp : 404
pusher.min.js:8 Pusher : No callbacks on private-test for pusher:subscription_error
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For private channels, you need to set-up the authentication route for your channel. In your `routes/channels.php`, there should be something like this:

```
Broadcast::channel('test', function ($user) {
    return true; // change this to your authentication logic.
});
```